# Missing required field '"timingCategory"' and '"timingVar"' for hit of type '"timing"' - Google Analytics [redux-beacon]

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, redux, redux-beacon

I'm using `redux-beacon` to send Google Analytics Hits. It is working fine with `Event Tracking` but failed with `User Timings`. As I can read on [doc for User Timing](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/user-timings), it requires `timingCategory`, `timingVar`, and `timingValue` but `redux-beacon` is sending it without `timing` prefix.

The following code produces a valid event in the redux-beacon logs for the `trackEvent` and failed for the `trackTiming`.

```
import {trackTiming, trackEvent} from '@redux-beacon/google-analytics';

const userTiming = trackTiming(action => {
  return {
    category: 'Test category',
    var: 'load',
    value: 3549,
    label: action.type
  };
});

const event = trackEvent(action => {
  return {
    category: 'Test category',
    action: action.type,
    label: 'Test label',
    value: 45
  };
});

export const eventsMap = {
  USER_TIMING_ACTION: userTiming,
  EVENT_ACTION: event
};
```

It gives me following error:

```
Running command: ga("send", {hitType: "timing", customTrackerId: undefined, category: "Test category", var: "load", value: 3549, label: "USER_TIMING_ACTION"})
Set called on unknown field: "customTrackerId".
Set called on unknown field: "category".
Set called on unknown field: "var".
Set called on unknown field: "value".
Set called on unknown field: "label".

Missing required field '"timingCategory"' for hit of type '"timing"'
Missing required field '"timingVar"' for hit of type '"timing"'
```

This is what `redux-beacon` print in console for `userTracking`:

```
hitType: "timing", customTrackerId: undefined, category: "Test category", var: "load", value: 3549, var: "load"}
```

I'm doing something wrong or is it a bug with `redux-beacon` for tracking timing?

Versions I'm using:

```
"@redux-beacon/google-analytics": "1.0.2",
"@redux-beacon/logger": "1.0.0",
"redux-beacon": "2.0.3"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug with the event helper. It's fixed now. Please upgrade to the latest version of the GA target:

```
npm install --save @redux-beacon/google-analytics@1.0.3
```

As an added tip. If there's ever an issue with an event helper you can easily do without them If you need a quick fix.

For example, in your situation you could write:

```
const userTiming = action => ({
  hitType: 'timing',
  timingCategory: 'Test category',
  timingVar: 'load',
  timingLabel: action.type,
});

export const eventsMap = {
  USER_TIMING_ACTION: userTiming,
};
```

Here are the docs on writing event definitions: 
https://rangle.gitbook.io/redux-beacon/index-1/event-definition

Thanks for taking the time to write up, ask a question, and highlight the issue you had. With so many different targets and event helpers bug reports like these are super helpful.